# How to get Eclipse browser to open to specified @WebServlet URL for servlet

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

So I created a new "Dynamic Web Project" in Eclipse IDE (2019-09 R 4.13.0). I called the project "MyProject". When creating this project I specified a Target runtime of Apache Tomcat 9.0 and a Dynamic web module version of 4.0.

For the project and under "Java Resources/src", I created a simple servlet. I called the servlet "TestServlet". And for that servlet I am using the @WebServlet("/TestServlet") annotation. Servlet code below.

When I right-click directly on the "TestServlet" servlet class from the Eclipse project explorer and choose Run As->Run on Server, Eclipse successfully opens its built-in browser.

However, here is where I think there's a problem.

The Eclipse browser opens to http://localhost:8080/MyProject/. This is the behavior that I would expect to see if I had clicked Run As->Run on Server from the /MyProject project folder. But, I clicked Run As->Run on Server from the TestServlet class under /MyProject/Java Resources/src/TestServlet.java class. Therefore, I would expect the Eclipse browser to open to http://localhost:8080/MyProject/TestServlet.

Am I wrong about this?

I am running on Tomcat 9 and JRE 1.8.

Note that if I manually type "http://localhost:8080/MyProject/TestServlet" as the URL in the Eclipse browser, the servlet runs as expected.

Any help figuring this out is appreciated!

```
package com.myproject.demo;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

/**
 * Servlet implementation class TestServlet
 */
@WebServlet("/TestServlet")
public class TestServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    /**
     * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
     */
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.getWriter().append("Served at: ").append(request.getContextPath());
    }

}
```

Comment: I don't understand. `localhost:8080/` *is* the root URL. Extra slashes are ignored.

Comment: Oops, sorry. The text got all garbled when I was trying to give generic references using < and >. I rewrote the problem statement. Hopefully that clears things up. Thank you.

Comment: This works, as it should, when I try it with the current release: 2019-09.

Comment: Hello @Nitind, what do you consider "it working as it should"? Which URL does the browser open to? I upgraded my Eclipse IDE to 2019-09 and I get the same results explained in the post.

Comment: What you intended, that it goes directly to the servlet.